# MPLAB X PICkit3 programmer unavailable

Tags: pic, pickit, mplabx

When trying to program a project in MPLAB X IDE using the PICkit 3 programmer, it fails as MPLAB X shows this error:

[image]

I have connected the PICkit3 with USB.
I'm using OS X 10.9 and the latest version of MPLAB X.

Hovering over the PICkit3 option in the tool selector shows this:

[image]

Comment: I take it when you select the PICkit3 it won't let you proceed? I've had the same error under Windows and removing the device driver, rebooting and installing the driver again fixed it although I'm not sure how you do that under OSX. Is there somewhere you can view the status of connected USB devices?

Comment: @PeterJ It will let me proceed, however when I click the program button it will pop up again, eg. program button -> tool select dialog -> ok -> program button -> ... Do you mean in MPLAB X or in OS X?

Comment: Sounds like a different problem to what I had. Mine was a general Windows USB driver problem of some sort but once I re-installed it went away (and it wouldn't let me proceed until it was fixed).

Comment: Is there a difference between what you see when plugged and when unplugged? If MPLAB cannot see your Pickit3 at all, chances are that it is broken. In that case you may ask Microchip support (I have heard of cases when they sent a replacement device).

Comment: @LaszloValko It works when using "PICkit 3 Programmer" (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PICkit3%200.2.0.3%20Setup.zip) on a Windows PC, so the PICkit hardware works.

Comment: @LaszloValko But there is no difference between having it plugged in and not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had installed MPLAB X to a custom directory instead of the default one, which seems to have caused the problem.

Uninstalling it and installing it again in the default directory fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your Pickit 3 must be as MPLAB mode, you can change it in PICKIT 3 standalone aplication.